# how to get the diffs from two/three files and combine them in node?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webpack

I have been playing with webpack and I was able to output and transform es5 buid to have nomodule in the tags directly from HtmlWebpackPlugin using hooks. Same for the es6 build but putting type="module".

The problem now is that I have two html files based in the same template files.
Here is an example, please don't mind the missing tags it is to illustrate what happens.
template.html:

```
<body class="container">
</body>
```

es5.main.html

```
 <link href="main.ef35cd992b2eaf651405.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <body class="container">
    </body>
  <script src="runtime.1ee16c2201d417984a0f.bundle.es5.js" nomodule></script>
```

es6.main.html

```
 <link href="main.ef35cd992b2eaf651405.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <body class="container">
    </body>
<script src="runtime.f00dbe9b3232d30ba93f.bundle.es6.js" type="module"></script>
```

I was wondering that after the build I could just run a node script to get the diff from the dist folder and combine it into a single file. Any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: What OS are you on? On Mac and Linux this would be easy. On Windows this is easy in gitbash or MinGW or some Linux distro running on WSL

Comment: I am on windows, but I do have bash installed. I do need this to be possible to run from cli so I can integrate with webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the this gist:
https://gist.github.com/agoldis/21782f3b9395f78d28dce23e3b6ddd56